# storm hdfs connector ... trying to write data into hdfs using storm

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-storm

I am trying to write data into HDFS using "storm-hdfs connector 0.1.3". 
The github URL: https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-hdfs,I have added this dependency into my maven project.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.ptgoetz</groupId>
      <artifactId>storm-hdfs</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The sample topology to write the data into HDFS is provided in the storm-hdfs project itself. I just modified it to match to my file locations. The HdfsFileTopology is :

```
package my.company.app;

import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;
import backtype.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichBolt;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichSpout;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;
import org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.HdfsBolt;
import org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.AbstractHdfsBolt;
import org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.SequenceFileBolt;
import org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.format.DefaultFileNameFormat;
import org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.format.DelimitedRecordFormat;
import org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.format.FileNameFormat;
import org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.format.RecordFormat;
import org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.rotation.FileRotationPolicy;
import org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.rotation.FileSizeRotationPolicy;
import org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.rotation.FileSizeRotationPolicy.Units;
import org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.rotation.TimedRotationPolicy;
import org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.sync.CountSyncPolicy;
import org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.sync.SyncPolicy;
import org.apache.storm.hdfs.common.rotation.MoveFileAction;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class HdfsFileTopology {
static final String SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID = "sentence-spout";
static final String BOLT_ID = "my-bolt";
static final String TOPOLOGY_NAME = "test-topology";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Config config = new Config();
    config.setNumWorkers(1);

    SentenceSpout spout = new SentenceSpout();

    // sync the filesystem after every 1k tuples
    SyncPolicy syncPolicy = new CountSyncPolicy(1000);

    // rotate files when they reach 5MB
    FileRotationPolicy rotationPolicy = new TimedRotationPolicy(1.0f, TimedRotationPolicy.TimeUnit.MINUTES);

   FileNameFormat fileNameFormat = new DefaultFileNameFormat()
            .withPath("/users/storm/")
            .withExtension(".txt");



    // use "|" instead of "," for field delimiter
    RecordFormat format = new DelimitedRecordFormat()
            .withFieldDelimiter("|");

    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[1]);
    Map<String, Object> yamlConf = (Map<String, Object>) yaml.load(in);
    in.close();
    config.put("hdfs.config", yamlConf);

    HdfsBolt bolt = new HdfsBolt()
            .withConfigKey("hdfs.config")
            .withFsUrl(args[0])
            .withFileNameFormat(fileNameFormat)
            .withRecordFormat(format)
            .withRotationPolicy(rotationPolicy)
            .withSyncPolicy(syncPolicy)
            .addRotationAction(new MoveFileAction().toDestination("/dest2/"));

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout(SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID, spout, 1);
    // SentenceSpout --> MyBolt
    builder.setBolt(BOLT_ID, bolt, 4)
            .shuffleGrouping(SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID);

    if (args.length == 2) {
        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();

        cluster.submitTopology(TOPOLOGY_NAME, config, builder.createTopology());
        waitForSeconds(120);
        cluster.killTopology(TOPOLOGY_NAME);
        cluster.shutdown();
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (args.length == 3) {
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], config, builder.createTopology());
    } else{
        System.out.println("Usage: HdfsFileTopology [topology name] <yaml config file>");
    }
}

public static void waitForSeconds(int seconds) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

public static class SentenceSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
    private ConcurrentHashMap<UUID, Values> pending;
    private SpoutOutputCollector collector;
    private String[] sentences = {
            "my dog has fleas",
            "i like cold beverages",
            "the dog ate my homework",
            "don't have a cow man",
            "i don't think i like fleas"
    };
    private int index = 0;
    private int count = 0;
    private long total = 0L;

    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("sentence", "timestamp"));
    }

    public void open(Map config, TopologyContext context,
                     SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
        this.pending = new ConcurrentHashMap<UUID, Values>();
    }

    public void nextTuple() {
        Values values = new Values(sentences[index], System.currentTimeMillis());
        UUID msgId = UUID.randomUUID();
        this.pending.put(msgId, values);
        this.collector.emit(values, msgId);
        index++;
        if (index >= sentences.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        count++;
        total++;
        if(count > 20000){
            count = 0;
            System.out.println("Pending count: " + this.pending.size() + ", total: " + this.total);
        }
        Thread.yield();
    }

    public void ack(Object msgId) {
        this.pending.remove(msgId);
    }

    public void fail(Object msgId) {
        System.out.println("**** RESENDING FAILED TUPLE");
        this.collector.emit(this.pending.get(msgId), msgId);
    }
}

public static class MyBolt extends BaseRichBolt {

    private HashMap<String, Long> counts = null;
    private OutputCollector collector;

    public void prepare(Map config, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        this.counts = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        this.collector = collector;
    }

    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        collector.ack(tuple);
    }

    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        // this bolt does not emit anything
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup() {
    }
}
}
```

I compile the project using maven (group id : my.company.app) and the build is successful but when I submit the jar file to storm it throws error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/storm/hdfs/bolt/format/FileNameFormat
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.format.FileNameFormat
```

Even though I have included the class,why is it throwing an error that the class was not found? 
And any help in how to write data to HDFS using storm will be appreciated.

As requested the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>hdfs_example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>hdfs_example</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>Codehaus</id>
          <url>http://repository.codehaus.org</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
          <id>Codehaus.Snapshots</id>
          <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org</url>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>github-releases</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github-releases/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>clojars.org</id>
            <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
      <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0M8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
      <artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2-incubating</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.ptgoetz</groupId>
      <artifactId>storm-hdfs</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test/main/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/multilang</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass></mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
    <!--  
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
        <artifactId>clojure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.12</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <sourceDirectories>
            <sourceDirectory>src/clj</sourceDirectory>
          </sourceDirectories>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
   -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>java</executable>
          <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
          <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
          <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
          <mainClass>${storm.topology}</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>  
</project>
```

Comment: Seems to me this is a packaging problem. Did you use the maven-shade plugin like Taylor suggested? Your topology looks ok to me at first glance but really this seems like a pom.xml issue.

Comment: Agreed. Could you post your pom.xml?

Comment: @Kit yes I did use the maven-shade plugin, it is the first plugin in the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and after checking pom.xml in detail I realized that in dependency of storm-hdfs `<version>0.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>` has scope defined as included which I think means that we have to add jar into storm jar and maven wont do it during packaging.

I changed version to what is available in maven repo and removed the scope which forced maven to download jar and include it in storm jar during build.

Here is my pom.xml for reference(with some basic details removed):

src/main/resources/
        false
        
          core-site.xml
          hdfs-site.xml

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
            <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>com.company.main</mainClass>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

</plugins>
```

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.2-incubating</version>
  <!-- keep storm out of the jar-with-dependencies -->
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.2-incubating</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Utilities -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>15.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.1.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
      <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
      <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
      <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
      <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
      <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- our cluster hadoop version -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- our cluster hadoop version -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>


<!-- apache hdfs-bolt related dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.ptgoetz</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm-hdfs</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.2</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```